# URLGOTO {{!VAR2}} not working, any ideas?

Tags: javascript, imacros

I'm currently working on a customized macro and on the code below, everything is working out fine, except the last line. Anyone who could point out what's wrong with my code?

Its a simple URLGOTO but the link is dynamic and stored in a variable.

```
VERSION BUILD=9030808 RECORDER=FX
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
SET !VAR1 www.website.com/
TAB T=1
TAG POS=10 TYPE=A ATTR=CLASS:*notranslate* EXTRACT=TITLE

'Tab T=2
PROMPT {{!VAR1}}{{!EXTRACT}}

SET !VAR2 {{!VAR1}}{{!EXTRACT}}

'this line doesn't work.. any idea?
URLGOTO={{!VAR2}}
```

my problem is this line:

> ```
> URLGOTO={{!VAR2}}
> ```

Im not sure how to implement this. Any help please? Thank you!

Comment: URL GOTO={{!VAR2}}

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments by **macroscripts**, your code has a slight typo:
`URLGOTO={{!VAR2}}` should be `URL GOTO={{!VAR2}}`, basically just add a space between URL and GOTO.